# How to use D3 Graph(d3.v3.min.js) with parameters in Ext JS 5 MVVM?

Tags: extjs, d3.js, extjs5

I have to create D3 graph (d3.v3.min.js) with parameters in Ext JS 5 MVVM.

I have created it but it is not working for my required parameters and I do not know how to call its d3.text(URL+Parameter) method on event of my Ext JS Component.

Please guide me if you have answer for this question.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fiddle which demonstrates a simple bar chart in ExtJS panel.

Please check [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/CqCDU/).